# How to fixed Call to 'div' is ambiguous with Xcode 9 final release

Tags: objective-c++

Do you have any ideas? Plz, help, thank you.

```
div_t divHour = div([comps hour],  12); 
return divHour.rem;
```

and show me the error above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the C++ standard library. In C, there is one function `div()` that returns a `div_t`. In C++, there's multiple overloads of `div()` that take different argument types and return different return types. And your call is ambiguous because `[comps hour]` returns an `NSInteger`, but your `12` is an `int`, so it can't figure out which overload to use.

There's two reasonable ways to fix this. The first is to cast to `int`:

```
div_t divHour = div((int)[comps hour],  12);
```

The second is to unambiguously use the `long` version:

```
ldiv_t divHour = div([comps hour],  12l);
```